# How to replace old Ubuntu with new Ubuntu (Dual boot), not given option to "Replace"

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

I am dual booting Windows/Ubuntu. When I boot my new Ubuntu installation media I am not given the option to "Replace" the old version, jut either make a new partition or replace the whole disk. Is there a reason why I am not given the "Replace" old Ubuntu with the new version option?

(P.S. I currently have Kubuntu and it has stopped loading so want to replace it with a new version.)

Thank you

Comment: Just choose "something else" and manually format your Kubuntu partition, and tell it to install there after so doing.

Comment: The old "Replace" option would still wipe the entire disk, you are lucky it was removed.

Answer (score 1):

- Boot into your live media.
- Choose `Try Ubuntu Without Installing Option`
  (This is so that if you have any problems or need to run any tools you can have access to the OS for help).
- Run the `Install Ubuntu` Application.
- Answer the prompts with defaults until you get to the `Install Type` screen.  Select `Something else` and click continue.
- Select the `ext4` partition of your old installation.

  1. Select change
  2. for `Use as` seledt `Ext4` in the dropdown.
  3. for `Mount point` Select `/`.
     4 for `format` you have a choice.  If you want to keep your personal files from the previous install leave it unchecked.  Check mark it to format if you want your to remove your personal files from the old install.
- Click `Install Now` and complete the prompts for personal information... reboot when prompted.